# How to get a string of certain font text in a NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, nstextview

I use different fonts in a `NSTextView`, what I want to do is to display a string of text of a certain font in a tableView.

How can I enumerate `textView.attributedString()` and get that string of certain text with a `NSFont` name as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to try running this code currently, but I believe the following should help you:

```
NSMutableArray *matchingStrings = [NSMutableArray new];
[attributedText enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                                    inRange:NSMakeRange(0,attributedText.length)
                                    options:0
                                 usingBlock:(void (^ nonnull)(UIFont *font,
                                 NSRange range,
                                 BOOL * nonnull stop)){
    if ([font.fontName isEqualToString: @"AvenirNext-Bold"])
    {
         NSAttributedString *attributedSubstring = [attributedText attributedSubstringFromRange:range];
        [matchingStrings addObject:attributedSubstring.string];
    }
}];
```